# Accessing page directly by URL shows blank page in codeigniter search

Tags: forms, codeigniter, search

I'm working on a project in which if I try to search query it shows results, but if I try to access same page through same URL it shows blank page.any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**My controller**

Here is my search function

```
public function search($keyword = "default", $city = "NULL")
    {

            $keyword = $this->input->get();

            $data['city_name']  =   $keyword['city'];
            $data['service_name']   =   str_replace('-',' ',$keyword['search']);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($data); die('kk');

// get sponsor data by city

    $data['sponsor']    =   $this->Home_model->getSponsor($keyword['city']);

            $data['packercontent'] =    $this->Home_model->getPackerContent($keyword['city']);
            $data['packers']  = $this->Home_model->get_results($keyword);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($keyword);die;
            $data['info']           =   $this->Home_model->getSiteInfo();

            $data['page']   =   '';
            $this->load->view('viw_packers', $data);


    }
```

**My modal**

```
     // get all packers according to city
     public function get_results($keyword = 'default')
      {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like('service', str_replace('-',' ',$keyword['search']));
        $this->db->where('city', $keyword['city']);
        $query  = $this->db->get('pf_package');

        return $query->result();
      }

// get all sponsor according to city
      public function getSponsor($city)
      {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('sp_city',$city);
        $this->db->from('pf_sponsor');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
      }

// get all packer content according to city
      public function getPackerContent($city)
      {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('city',$city);
        $this->db->from('pf_packers_content');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
      }
```

**My view file**

```
  <form class="form-inline" id="myForm" method="get" action="">
          <div class="form-group row nomargin">
                                <div class="servicewrap col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 nopadding">
              <select class="form-one-class" name="search" id="service">
               <option value="moving-locally">Moving Locally</option>
               <option value="moving-overseas">Moving Overseas</option>
               <option value="corporate-relocation">Corporate Relocation</option>
               <option value="commercial-relocation">Commercial Relocation</option>
               <option value="packaging-services">Packaging Services</option>
               <option value="storage-services">Storage Services</option>
             </select>
                                </div><!-- /.servicewrap -->

                                <div class="citywrap col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 nopadding">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" autocomplete="off" placeholder="select city">
              <div id="category-suggestions">
                   <div class="suggestions col-xs-12" id="category-autoSuggestionsList">

                   </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.citywrap -->
                                <div class="buttonwrap col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 nopadding">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search-button" >search</button>
                                </div><!-- /.buttonwrap -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**Here is my js code**

I call my search form action through js.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search-button").click(function(e){
    var city = $("#city").val();
    var lowerCity = '-'+city.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("myForm").action = "<?php echo base_url('search/packers-and-movers-in'); ?>"+lowerCity;
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It is simple, because you are using post request, if you hit url directly, your ```$_POST``` is empty and you will get nothing but blank page. Try to use ```$_GET``` parameters instead ```$_POST```, you will get results.

Comment: thanks @kishor10d for your reply. i will try this.

Comment: @kishor10d now its working but i want to show url like this http://localhost/profilehome/search/packers-and-movers-in-jaipur, instead of this http://localhost/profilehome/search/packers-and-movers-in-jaipur?search=moving-locally&city=Jaipur

Comment: Now i want to remove this ?search=moving-locally&city=Jaipur from my url

Comment: I think you get the framework wrong, it is supporting pretty urls, not querystring, until you change the config.
You can do the thing by pretty urls. You just need to take input from url serially and then send them to compare in queries

http://localhost/profilehome/search/packers-and-movers-in-jaipur/moving-locally/Jaipur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your controller function

```
public function search($keyword = "default", $city = NULL)
{
$data["sponcer"] = $this->your_model->searchByKeyword($keyword);
$data["packerContent"] = $this->your_model->searchByKeyword($city);

$this->load->view("yourview", $data);
}
```

This is just demo code, you need to frame your by your need. You don't really need `$_GET` to get the values from querystring.

If you write above code then your url like :
http://localhost/profilehome/search/packers-and-movers-in-jaipur/Jaipur

check the documentation here :
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: is there any other way to do this?. i remove get parameters using javascript but now the url not working again when i visit again same url. please help what i do to get this work. thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: what is the point of removing get parameter by javascript? Have you read the documentation carefully?

Comment: the only point of removing get parameter by javascript is to obtain a clean url for my website. I already throughout with documentation, please let me know if i missed anything specific about this particular topic.

Comment: can you update your code in question itself, what you tried after my answer?

Comment: i have updated my code. this is my original code that i use now after your answer. please help me i am new in ci i have no experience yet. and i don't know how to do this. any help would be appreciated. Thanks